# Bootstrap 4 Dropdown - Disable auto placement caused by popper.js

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I'm working with Bootstrap 4 dropdown and there are about 18 dropdown items.
Because the height is too much, popper.js automatically moves the dropdown away from its original position to the top of the screen. How do I prevent this?
I always want the dropdown to appear right below the button that toggles it.
Thanks

Posting code as requested - ( I'm using C# but the code should convey the point I'm hoping)

```
             <div class="dropdown">
                <span class="p-2 text-uppercase font-weight-semi-bold pointer dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    @topMenu.Name
                </span>
                <div class="dropdown-menu"  style="font-size:0.9rem" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    @foreach (var subMenu in topMenu.SubMenu)
                    {
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="@Url.Content("~/" + subMenu.Url)">@subMenu.Name</a>

                    }
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hi Zim I've added the code but I don't think it is specific to the code. It is bootstrap 4 dropdown functionality in general I think? Let me know thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4.1**

There is a new "display" option that disables popper.js dropdown positioning. Use `data-display="static"` to [prevent popper.js from dynamically changing the dropdown position](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#options)...

**Bootstrap 4.0**

There are some issues with `popper.js` and positioning.

I've found the solution is to `position-relative` the `.dropdown`, and set it as the `data-boundary=""` option in the dropdown toggle: 
https://www.codeply.com/go/zZJwAuwC5s

```
  <div class="dropdown position-relative" id="dd">
        <button type="button" data-boundary="dd" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Dropdown
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
            ...
        </div>
   </div>
```

The `boundary` is set to the `id` of the dropdown. Read more about [data-boundary](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#options).

---

Related questions:
[Bootstrap 4: Why popover inside scrollable dropdown doesn't show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319865/bootstrap-4-why-popover-inside-scrollable-dropdown-doesnt-show)
[Scrolling a dropdown in a modal in Bootstrap4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168548/scrolling-a-dropdown-in-a-modal-in-bootstrap4)

Comment: hi, I have the exact same problem, only I add the popover content dynamically on page load, I tried your `data-display="static"` but it still jumps up to the top of the viewport everytime the content does not fit the screen, please how do I make the `body` scroll, instead of the popover move, thanx

Answer (score 8):

I achieved this in Bootstrap 4.3.1 by adding `data-flip="false"` to the dropdown element.

ex:
`<a href="#" id="drop2" data-toggle="dropdown"  data-flip="false">dropdown</a>`

Answer (score 2):

ZimSystems got it almost right in Bootstrap 4.1. To disable the dropdown changing direction while open, aka. it's x-placement="bottom-end", you should use the "flip" option, instead of the "display" option.

Display static disables the positioning entirely, while flip only disables the LIVE checks, that flip the dropdown upside down, when you scroll towards the top of the screen.

Comment: what?... and how do you do that? every answer need an example ;)

Answer (score -1):

In options, you can try to change `dropupAuto : true` to `dropupAuto : false`.
https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/#bootstrap-version