# how to disable auto position of bootstrap 4.1

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My current dropdown list is large. See the image below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXvvL.png)

How to fix this issue? I'm thinking of using proper JS to reposition the menu.
Please help. How can I disable auto-positioning?

**Here's an example of my code**

```
<div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Action
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**NOTE :** When I scroll the page, an inline css applies on dropdown menu, and change css property as screen scroll. How can I fix this issue?

```
element.style {
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(16px, -258px, 0px);
    top: 0px;
    will-change: transform;
}
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: What is your aim here? to have a shorter dropdown list?

Comment: You mean, the height is too large?

Comment: proper js change the inline style according to screen size. i want to stop or disable that.
element.style {
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(16px, -258px, 0px);
    top: 0px;
    will-change: transform;
}

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable, you must use some negative trick with only css.You need to write some css to overwrite css.So, you can use transform unset like

```
.dropdown-menu.show {
  transform: unset !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query correctly, you're Bootstrap 4 dropdown is larger than you want. To resolve, you could add an overflow to the `dropdown-menu`

```
.menu-scroll {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: not its not right solution. can you tell me how can i disable proper js in dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

Add a class next to dropdown-menu, for example .menu-scrolling and then set custom css:

---

```
.menu-scrolling {
          min-height: 1oopx!important; /*Your value */
          max-height: 250px!important; /*Your value*/
          overflow-y: auto!important;
        }
```

Comment: its not solution
https://imgur.com/a/eIOCbHX 
if we fix the menu with height so its child menu will be hide,

Comment: the element style change according to screen size i don't know why.
here is style

Comment: element.style {
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(16px, -258px, 0px);
    top: 0px;
    will-change: transform;
}

Comment: You should put overflow-x:hidden, and put those changes only for the one element, no to the child ones.

Comment: i want to disable proper js auto positioning. can you tell me how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323672/bootstrap-4-dropdown-disable-auto-placement-caused-by-popper-js maybe this can help then

Answer (score 0):

**Put this line in your js file.**

```
Popper.Defaults.modifiers.preventOverflow = { enabled: false };
```

**for disable proper js.**

and add some parameter in dropdown(data-flip="false",data-boundary="window" ) like this

```
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" data-flip="false" data-boundary="window" aria-expanded="true"  >
                <i class="icon-menu "></i>
                <span class="change-text">Select a Category</span>
            </a>
```