# Dynamic drop down. Toggle only showing in first drop down

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm inserting Dropdowns into a dynamic form. The problem is when i insert more than one Dropdown.

When i click on any Dropdown button, the toggle list only shows above the first Dropdown button, not above the Dropdown button i clicked.

So say i have 3 Dropdown buttons inserted into the form. If i click Dropdown 2 or 3; the list of contents show above Dropdown 1.

This is the code i'm inserting into the form.

```
let vendor = `<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu test" id="vendor['+nextindex+']" name="vendor['+nextindex+']" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#" data-value="action">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="another action">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="something else here">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>`
```

Comment: Can you create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using a runnable HTML/CSS/JavaScript [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? Include only what is necessary to replicate the issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution.
[Bootstrap 4 Dropdown - Disable auto placement caused by popper.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323672/bootstrap-4-dropdown-disable-auto-placement-caused-by-popper-js)

It was an Issue with popper.js.